# Counting number of successes and failures in TESTNG and Java (selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I have a little JAVA program that login into a website

```
package testingProgram;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testingProgram {

    @Test
    public void helloWorldTest() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

        driver.get("https://website234/backend/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.close();
        
        WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver2.get("https://website234/backend/");
        driver2.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver2.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("admin2");
    }
}
```

> Note: in my example the correct login is:
>
> username = admin and password = admin

---

It opens 2 chrome sessions and tries to login by using different passwords.

If it fails login it throws and error message like this:

[image]

My testng test shows this:

[image]

But i want the output to tell me how many tests passed and in my case only one username and password worked correctly.

**Expected result:**

```
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1 (username = admin, password = admin), Failures: 1 (username = admin, password = admin2), Skips: 0
```

because i was able to login by using username = admin and password = admin but it wont be able to login using username = admin and password = admin2

How can i achieve something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong:

1. Even you have 2 initialize driver, your script recognized as one test only.
2. You have to give a condition how to submit a successful login.
3. For `username` and `password`, looks like you want the logs, but it doesn't look like it's set at all.

Approach:

1. Create 2 `@Test` annotation for each test.
2. Mark what a successful login looks like., mostly with **`welcome home`**
3. Logs set, with : `import org.testng.Reporter;`

```
@Test
public void helloWorldTest1() {
    ....

    //logs set
    String username = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    Reporter.log("username = " +username, true);
    Reporter.log("password = " +password, true);

    driver.get("https://website234/backend/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys(password);
    //here, i think need to submit login button
    buttonLogin.click();
    
    //here, find a welcome home locator maybe
    WebElement welcomeHome = driver.findElement(By.name("a locator"));
}

@Test
public void helloWorldTest2() {
    ....

    //logs set
    String username = "admin";
    String password = "admin2";
    Reporter.log("username = " +username, true);
    Reporter.log("password = " +password, true);

    driver.get("https://website234/backend/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys(password);
    //here, i think need to submit login button
    buttonLogin.click();
    
    //here, find a welcome home locator maybe
    WebElement welcomeHome = driver.findElement(By.name("a locator"));
}
```

Console output:
[image: console output]

Note : You can see logs in default report too `emailable-report.html`:

[image: emailable-report.html]

Btw there is way to achive this still with one **`@Test`**, you can learn about [**`@DataProvider`**](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) and `invocationcount` to repeat this test with various parameter.

Comment: Hey pal, is it possible for you to give me an example using @DataProvider and invocationcount to repeat this test with various parameter? i dont want to run 500 different selenium.Mytest1,selenium.Mytest2,selenium.Mytest3,selenium.Mytest4, etc